# Not able to get response from HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, mono, google-api, httpresponse

I have following code written on mono (Mono on ubuntu)

```
string URI = "http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ekarkala%2Ein%2F/keywords/?access_token=ya29.ABCDEFGI7bzJmlLWtk290M-PkNx20ej9p6a0sxoaxFPe_7qypXuW7Q";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
request.Headers.Add("GData-Version", "2");
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The code is part of getting response from Google webmaster API.
But I get the following error while trying to get the response

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

System
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0

If I copy-paste the same URI on my browser, I am able to see the xml response.

Comment: If that is really your access key, you really should edit your question and replace that with a dummy key.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the request content type:

`request.ContentType = "text/xml";`

Otherwise, the remote server won't know what to do with your request.

Comment: Pasting the uri into the browser only proves that the web request will get data back, browsers parse responses automatically where as your code won't until you tell it to and how. I suggest you first try aevitas's solution and if that does not work then try use Chromes Postman or some other SOAP client.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the way the value of the URI is encoded?
Have you tried using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

It has very nice features for you to investigate the web request.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I am using in Xamarin which gets a CSRF token, but from this you can see how I set up my request. Pretty much as aevitas says, you need to specify the Content-Type as per line 3

```
public JsonToken getCSRFToken(){
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(this.apiBaseUrl + @"/druidapi/user/token.json"));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        Console.Out.WriteLine("GET call to: {0}", this.apiBaseUrl.ToString() + @"/druidapi/user/token.json");

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content)) {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                }
                else {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
                }

                if (content == null) {
                    throw new Exception ("content is NULL");
                } else {

                    JsonToken deserializedToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonToken>(content);
                    return deserializedToken;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```